# Grails: How do I map a URL to a controller inside a custom plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, tags, include

I have a controller inside a **plugin** called `TextController` with an action called `index`

I then have a view inside the **calling application** called `test-plugin.gsp` with the following include tag:

```
<g:include controller="text" />
```

This works great. The problem is that the plugin's controller actually needs to identified by a package-like name, such as: `com.foxbomb.fxportal3.components.text`, and I need to reference it as such. So my thinking us to try and have a URL mapping for the plugin, such as:

```
    "/components/com.foxbomb.fxportal3.components.text/" {
        controller = "text"
        action = "index"
    }
```

I also don't know how to create an include in the calling application to try and call that URL, something like (I know you don't get a URL attribute):

```
<g:include url="/components/com.foxbomb.fxportal3.components.text"/>
```

In other words, I want to include a controller / action by its ***mapping*** as opposed to its controller / action ***name***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<g:include>` doesn't allow a `url` attribute, which surprises me, but looking at [the source of the `<g:include>` tag](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.1.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/RenderTagLib.groovy#L55) it should be possible to implement this in your own taglib fairly easily (untested):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils

class IncludeTagLib {
  def grailsUrlMappingsHolder

  def includeUri = { attrs, body ->
    def mapping = grailsUrlMappingsHolder.match(attrs.uri)
    out << WebUtils.includeForUrlMappingInfo(request, response, mapping,
               attrs.model ?: [:])?.content
  }
}
```

You'd say `<g:includeUri uri="/components/com.foxbomb.fxportal3.components.text"/>` in your GSP.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your answer. components isn't the context path. It's simply the path I added to the mapping file. Still can't access the plugin URL through the application via URL. Also, you didn't mention how I can solve the "include a controller in a plugin with the following URL mapping". Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkvanWyk OK, I get where you're coming from now.  See my latest edit for a possible solution.

Comment: I could kiss you right now, but I'm not that way inclined, and that would just be a bit weird, so I'll just give you a +1 and an Accepted Answer instead. Yeah, you can take it as a thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to read the model on the other side? (receiving controller). The chainModel is not populated and flash is empty.

Comment: @MarkvanWyk I don't think the included request has access to the original model directly, but you can pass a `model` attribute to the tag: `<g:includeUri uri="..." model="[foo:foo, bar:bar]" />`.  You _might_ even get away with `model="${pageScope.variables}"` to pass the whole current model through to the included action, you'd have to try it and see if anything breaks...